# Wordpress php grouping by ACF custom field result renders to many groups with copies of posts

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, advanced-custom-fields, posts

So, I'm basically trying to make an archive of posts which are ordered in groups after year. I'm using the **ACF date picker** and with a function `getProdYear();` I'm extracting the year from each date. Then I've tried to follow [this](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/possible-to-group-by-values-of-custom-field/) example
to create a group for each year.

PHP:

```
function getProdYear() {
    $dateBeg = get_field('prod_date_beg');
    $yB = substr($dateBeg, 0, 4);
    $mB = substr($dateBeg, 4, 2);
    $dB = substr($dateBeg, 6, 2);
    $timeB = strtotime("{$dB}-{$mB}-{$yB}");

    global $prod_year;
    $prod_year = date('Y' , $timeB );

}   

$args = array(
    'category_name' => 'produktion',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'order' => 'DSC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'prod_date_beg',
);

$posts = get_posts($args); 
$group_posts = array();

foreach($posts as $post) :
    setup_postdata( $post ); 

    getProdYear(); //run function to get year only from 'prod-date-beg' in $prod_year 

    if( !isset($group_posts[ $prod_year ]) )
    {
        $group_posts[ $prod_year ] = array();
    }

    $group_posts[ $prod_year ][] = $post; //create group

    //var_dump($group_posts);

    foreach ($group_posts as $year_group => $year_posts) {
        echo '<strong>'. $prod_year . '</strong>';
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($year_posts as $post) {
            echo '<li>'. get_the_title($post->ID) .'</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    } 
endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
```

The result I'm getting now is:
[image: unwanted result]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed it. I was looping inside a loop, by closing the `foreach($posts as $post)` before starting `foreach ($group_by_year as $year_name => $year_posts)` It group everything correctly. I also changed `echo '<strong>'. $prod_year . '</strong>';` to `echo '<strong>'. $year_name . '</strong>';` since the first repeated same name for each group.

Here's my working PHP:

```
    function getProdYear() {
    $dateBeg = get_field('prod_date_beg');
    $yB = substr($dateBeg, 0, 4);
    $mB = substr($dateBeg, 4, 2);
    $dB = substr($dateBeg, 6, 2);
    $timeB = strtotime("{$dB}-{$mB}-{$yB}");

    global $prod_year;
    $prod_year = date('Y' , $timeB );

}   

$args = array(
    'category_name' => 'produktion',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'order' => 'DSC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'prod_date_beg',
);

$posts = get_posts($args); 
$group_posts = array();

//loop through posts
foreach($posts as $post) {
    setup_postdata( $post ); 

    //run function to get year only from 'prod-date-beg' in $prod_year 
    getProdYear(); 

    //$add to so
    if( !isset($group_by_year[ $prod_year ]) )
    {
        $group_by_year[ $prod_year ] = array();
    }

    $group_by_year[ $prod_year ][] = $post; //create group

    }

    //loop through group_by_year    
    foreach ($group_by_year as $year_name => $year_posts) {
        echo '<strong>'. $year_name . '</strong>';
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($year_posts as $post) {
            echo '<li>'. get_the_title($post->ID) .'</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
wp_reset_postdata();
```